# Post category archive page with

Tags: php, wordpress

I`m looking to build a page with a grid of all my post categories.
not the posts, just the categories.
how I can do it?

Code or plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code, This code will get all post categories..

```
<?php
  $taxonomy     = 'category';
  $orderby      = 'name';  

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
    echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'category') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!
How I can get category image?

Comment: First accept it as solution of your current question after that will continue further..

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Page Template. And build [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) query. And print loop according to your design.